# How can a TinyMCE modal return formatted/visual text?

Tags: tinymce, editor, html-editor

I am trying to customize the behavior of an editor button in a plugin. On click, it opens a modal where the user can input some text. On confirmation, I want to wrap this text into code tags. But I don't want to take this text as if it comes from a text editor, I want to handle it as visual text. This means, I want to preserve any formatting (whitespaces and linebreaks) but not accept any other tags besides the code tags that I add afterward.

```
function showDialog() {
    var win = ed.windowManager.open({
            title: "Insert code",
            body: {
                type: 'textbox',
                name: 'code',
                multiline: true,
                minWidth: ed.getParam("code_dialog_width", 600),
                minHeight: ed.getParam("code_dialog_height", Math.min(tinymce.DOM.getViewPort().h - 200, 500)),
                spellcheck: false,
                style: 'direction: ltr; text-align: left'
            },
            onSubmit: function(e) {
                ed.focus();

                ed.undoManager.transact(function() {
                    ed.insertContent('<code>' + e.data.code + '</code>');
                });

                ed.selection.setCursorLocation();
                ed.nodeChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You mean like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PVgobL/left/?editors=1010)?

Comment: @SallyCJ Close! I also want to keep whitespaces in the beginning of each line if that's possible!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Revised answer)*

You can use `tinymce.DOM.encode()` to convert all HTML tags to their entities, e.g. `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>`:

```
var html = tinymce.DOM.encode(e.data.code);
```

Then to preserve trailing white-spaces:

```
html = html.replace(/(^ +| +$)/gm, function(match, p1){
  return p1.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
});
```

And this to convert all line breaks to `<br>`:

```
html = html.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

So your `onSubmit` would look like, which you can try [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMeZxa/left/?editors=1010):

```
onSubmit: function(e) {
  ed.focus();

  ed.undoManager.transact(function() {
    // Encode all HTML tags to their entities.
    var html = tinymce.DOM.encode(e.data.code);

    // Then convert trailing whitespaces to `&nbsp;`.
    html = html.replace(/(^ +| +$)/gm, function(match, p1){
      return p1.replace(/ /g, '&nbsp;');
    });

    // Finally, convert line breaks to `<br>`.
    html = html.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

    // Make sure the format is "raw".
    ed.insertContent('<code>' + html + '</code> ');
  });

  ed.selection.setCursorLocation();
  ed.nodeChanged();
}
```

*Credit to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/9217760) for the line breaks conversion.*

Comment: I think the whitespaces have to be converted to <p> </p> because I get &nbsp; everywhere in my output.

Comment: So multiple white-spaces become a `<p> </p>` and not for each white-space - e.g. `   ` (three spaces) is *not* `<p> </p><p> </p><p> </p>` (three `p`s)?

Comment: Right, it becomes <p>   </p> which contains all the empty spaces for that line

Comment: Check the updated answer and new [demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XOQbaW/left/?editors=1010).

Comment: This puts <p>  </p> with the same number of spaces infront of every line. It also puts it directly into the visual text. And I think the </p> has to enclose the text of each line as well.
Unfortunately I don't really know what has to be fixed because I have almost zero knowledge about this.
But you can see it in the demo link as well.

Comment: I don't really get the problem, but I'll look at it again later. Can you, however, show a screenshot highlighting the problem?

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. Here you can see the output when I try it with me code from the opening post:
https://imgur.com/a/DOYiwcd
As you can see, it puts the <p> </p> infront of each line into the visual editor and they always have the same space. Also, I think the closing </p> has to be at the end of the line, after the text.

Comment: Well, that's the expected output. I mean, with my code. Can you now show how the output should look like?

Comment: I want to preserve the spaces of the text that I copy in there. So when I copy in the code from my question, I want it to appear like this in the editor surrounded by <code> tags. Your first approach worked for line breaks, but it didn't keep the spaces. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible.. check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you. But this again removes all the whitespaces:
https://imgur.com/a/JGy8KtM

Comment: [Try again?](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xMeZxa/left/?editors=1010)

Comment: Still the same. Is it different on your end? I always lose the whitespaces infront of each line

Comment: Whops sorry, I had not updated the Pen.. try again.

Comment: It seems to work, thank you! It doesn't actually work properly in my plugin editor but I guess this is a problem on my side!
Thank you very much!